# Type mismatch inferred type is () -> Unit but FlowCollector<Int> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

When trying to collect from a Flow the type suddenly mismatches, and it was working and then started suddenly.

In my viewmodel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    lateinit var river: Flow<Int>

    fun doStuff() {
        river = flow {
            emit(1)
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
        .catch {
            emit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my activity I have the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.river.collect { it ->
        // this whole collect is what has the error. 
    }
}
```

But `collect` gives the error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but FlowCollector<Int> was expected`.

How could this be happening?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Probably, you are using [the direct `collect()` function on `Flow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/collect.html).

For your syntax, you need to `import` [the `collect()` extension function](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html).

(and I *really* wish that they did not name these the same...)

Comment: This gets me EVERY time

Comment: `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect`

Comment: DUDE, what a pitfall.

Comment: It does not work with `1.6.0`, I had to downgrade my application to keep it working. I hope to find a solution for that.

Comment: on 1.6.0 you need to use 'collect { action(it) } ' as a temp fix

Comment: This does not work anymore, it is a deprecated and hidden API now.

Comment: @shelll: [The documentation does not indicate that](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the imports are messing we me. In the extensions the last `collect` function is hidden https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/3fc1c20a87a689c09f062afc9e3ac347829d29f7/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/terminal/Collect.kt#L114

I cannot force to use the imported `collect` from `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect`, the import is note used/"grayed-out" so it is using the non-extension collect, thus complaints about type mismatch, expecting `FlowCollector`.

Comment: Looks like my problem is with collecting a `StateFlow`, just casting it to the base `Flow`, and collecting that, fixes the type mismatch problem.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same problem while trying to collect multiple flows from some datastore files. First of all, make sure that you have imported these two  dependencies in your app-level gradle file. Also ensure that you replace the version numbers with suitable versions.

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-beta01")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2")
```

After syncing your gradle files, import collect;

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
```

Your `collect{  }` should now work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution was to put parenthesis at the end of `collect`:

`viewModel.river.collect()`